# Connecting consequences and premises

Tags: phrase-requests, writing-advice

“Hence”, “therefore”, “ergo”, “so”, “thereupon”, and “thus” are examples of connectors where the premises are written before the conclusion. I am looking for ways to connect a consequence and its premises but I want to write the conclusion before the premises. The following examples show the construction sought.

> The sum of addends x and y is 5. **That follows from** x being 4 and y being 1.

The next one feels clumsy but it would still be acceptable.

> The sum of addends x and y is 5. **That is because** x is 4 and y is 1.

I do not want to use an “if…then…” construction where the premises are written before the conclusion. I need the conclusion at the start of the paragraph for dramatic effect. The conclusion might be a long and convoluted single sentence that needs to be referred to as a whole. That is the role played by “That” in “That follows from …” and “That is because …”

My main problem is that after re-using the construction in the examples, the prose becomes repetitive and dull. Thus, I need more similar constructions.

---

**Clarification**

Because the conclusion is a really long sentence, I cannot use “since” to join two clauses. Constructions such as “The sum of addends x and y is 5 where x is 4 and y is 1” is unsatisfactory for the same reason: The consequence is a long sentence by itself.

---

**Example**

In the original examples, the conclusion `The sum of addends x and y is 5.` was misleadingly simple. A situation closer to the my predicament is the following rewording of the Pythagorean Theorem.

> In a triangle, the square of the length of one of the sides is equal to the addition of the squares of the lengths of the other sides, within the limits of error propagation, as long as the angle enclosed by the other two sides is a right angle and the measurements of the lengths is carried out with rulers with similar spacing between tick marks. **That follows from** completing the triangle using the procedure detailed in the ancient textbooks …

Note that the first sentence is already 4 lines long. Trying to tie it with the next sentence to form an even longer sentence is not an option. Some of the constructions I have been using include are below. They sound clumsy to me because they use more than 3 words.

- That is a consequence of
- That is a result of
- That can be proven by

Comment: Your new example completely changes everything about your question—effectively negating all three answers already given that were based on something different.  Your first attempt at simplification resulted in nobody being able to give you a satisfactory answer. Please provide the *rest* of the second sentence so that more false assumptions are not made.

Comment: @JasonBassford I apologize for the confusion. Perhaps, my usage of “premise” and “conclusion” is not standard.

Comment: … As for the rest of the second sentence, it is irrelevant. Besides the sentences being rather long, the main point of the question is not about the sentences themselves. It is about changing the order of the exposition. When one writes `Sentence A. Hence, sentence B.`, one is putting in two sentences the logical relationship "if A then B". The one-word connectors “therefore”, “ergo”, etc. are basically interchangeable: `Sentence A. Ergo, sentence B.` conveys the same "if A then B" in two sentences. I want to write `Sentence B. Connector, sentence A.` and still mean "if A then B".

Comment: Consider: *In a triangle, the square of the length of one side is equal to something. Completing the triangle using procedure X accomplishes this.* I can say that because you've left your second sentence unfinished. Depending on *how* it's finished, I might not be able to say that. Context is always important.

Comment: Actually, your comment provides an interesting strategy. You put the “connector” at the end of the second sentence: `Sentence B. Sentence A justifies that.` I can work on making the second sentences shorter and use “accomplishes this”, “justifies that”, etc. as the connectors. Back to the original question, I hope the community can suggest more words/phrases that can be used in place of the bold phrases in the examples.

Comment: See also [writers.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

You want to emphasize the word "addends", and not lighten it up to "The sum of x and y is 5, when x is 4 and y is 1"?

> "The sum of addends x and y is 5". The preceding statement is always true when x is 4 and y is 1.
>
> "The sum of addends x and y is 5". Sufficient conditions for this to be true include the combination of x being 4 and y being 1.

Comment: I do not understand the "emphasize" versus "lighten up" part.

Comment: I was thinking that if you take the word "addends" out, it might be few enough words to use just one sentence, but I was also observing that you seem not to be looking for a one-sentence answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something I've seen is the use of **where**:

> The sum of addends x and y is 5 where x is 4 and y is 1.

Or, more like an actual equation:

> x+y=5 where x=4 and y=1.

Further explanation beyond just the value of the variables could then be provided in another sentence.

---

**Update**: It was made clear after I posted this answer that the question had been simplified—and that my use of **where** only matched the simplified scenario.

A more appropriate scenario is:

> Sentence 1: Dinosaurs are brought back to life, unicorns appear in zoos, and gravity is sometimes reversed during periods of stress.
>
> Sentence 2: A new reality machine.

Sentence 2 answers the question of how sentence 1 is accomplished.

What's being asked is what phrasing can be used to link the two sentences together.

---

In a comment, I suggested putting linking verbiage at the *end* of the second sentence rather than at its start:

> Dinosaurs are brought back to life. A new reality machine **accomplishes this**.

Changing the terminology to be more "proof" oriented, here are some other examples of terminal-linking verbiage:

> . . . causes this outcome.
> . . . makes this possible.
> . . . is used to reach this conclusion.

---

Similar verbiage can be used at the start of the second sentence:

> This is enabled by . . .
> Supporting this is . . .
> This conclusion is reached when . . .

---

As a point of grammar, the pronoun used here should be **this** rather than **that**. What's being referred to is sentence 1, which was just introduced. This is similar to something like the following:

> I have a pebble in my hand. This pebble is jagged.

Because the pebble is *close* to the speaker, **this** is used.

> There is a pebble in the room across the hallway. That pebble is jagged.

Here, **that** is used because it is at a distance from the speaker.

When sentence 2 refers to sentence 1, it is *conceptually* close:

> Here is my theory. This theory is a good one.

As opposed to:

> My colleague has a theory. That theory is a good one. (But not as good as *this* one.)

Comment: I have edited the question to make more prominent the requirement: Because the conclusion is a really long sentence, I cannot use “since” to join two clauses.

Comment: @Hector You will have to give an actual example of what you're describing if the problem is to be understood. Otherwise, it seems we can only speculate. Having a long sentence doesn't preclude sentences that come before it . . .

Comment: I have added another example.

Comment: @Hector I have updated my answer based on clarifying comments under your question.